# Generate a grid through an extensive area without killing my machine

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector-grid, tesselation, arcgis-10.6

I need to generate a grid of 10x10m on a certain extent so I can extract only the squares that have some area inside of a certain shape.

My problem is that the shape I need to extract those squares are just 60m wide, while being 400km long. Since it's the shape of an actual existent road and its vicinity, if we check it's extent, it's a rectangle of about 150x400km, and running a fishnet on it through ArcGIS comes back negative because the file size would be too big, and tessellation is taking so far 50 minutes and I'm afraid my CPU is overheating because of this.

Is there any way I can do this without having to make multiple instances of fishnet or tessellation, on ArcGIS 10.x, to merge them together later?

Comment: Raster is faster-vector is corrector!  Consider rasterizing your data if you do not have the processing power for the vector approach.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that "create fishnet" basically runs for the entire bounding box rectangle of your data - which can include a ton of empty area for irregularly shaped input like yours.

Have you tried  [Grid Index Features](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/cartography-toolbox/grid-index-features.htm) instead?  I think this would do the same as fishnet, but only for the extents of your input.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

You indicate that the problem is the size of the generated file. For shapefiles the maximum size is around 2 GB. For this reason alone shapefile use should be [discontinued](http://switchfromshapefile.org). Use [Geopackage](https://www.geopackage.org/) or [file geodatabase](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/file-geodatabases.htm) as your output format instead. Both of them support file sizes up to several terrabytes.

Your processor will not overheat as long as you do not overclock it, and its fans functionality is not in any way blocked. I have had both laptops and desktop computers running for days to end doing GIS tasks without any processor failiure. This does of course depend on the quality of your equipment. Also make sure you leave it running the shadow in an airconditioned room, and you should be fine.

In general time consuming processing tasks could be left to run overnight.